# Is there wights of voice or audio for VGG or Inception?

Tags: deep-learning, feature-engineering, transfer-learning, inception, vgg16

- I want to use `VGG16` (or `VGG19`) for voice clustering task.
- I read some articles which suggest to use `VGG` (16 or 19) in order to build the embedding vector for the clustering algorithm.
- The process is to convert the wav file into `mfcc` or `plot (Amp vs Time)` and use this as input to `VGG` model.
- I tried it out with `VGG19` (and `weights='imagenet'`).
- I got bad results, and I assumed it because I'm using `VGG` with wrong weights (weights of images (`imagenet`))

So:

1. Are there any audio/voice per-trained weights for VGG ?
2. If not, are there other per-trained audio /voice models ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [VVGish](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset/vggish) is the VGG adapted to audio processing. I can remember using it with mfcc, not Amp-Time input tho.

Answer (score 0):

Besides VGGish mentioned by @Ubikuity, there are other pre-trained audio models:

- PANNs by Qiuqiang Kong. As of July 2021 one of the best on general audio classification AudioSet. [PANNs @ Github](https://github.com/qiuqiangkong/panns_inference). Based on PyTorch
- YAMNet, by same team at Google as VGGish. [YAMNet @ TfHub](https://tfhub.dev/google/yamnet/1). Based on Tensorflow.
- OpenL3 by Music and Audio Research Laboratory at NYU. Very easy to get started with. [OpenL3 @ Github](https://github.com/marl/openl3). Based on Tensorflow/Keras.